# Why this Haskell expression won't get a result?

Tags: haskell

I try to run this in GHCi:

```
take 100 [ (a,b,c) | a <- [1..], b <- [1..], c <- [1..], a^2 + b^2 == c^2, a<b ]
```

I would expect it to be calculated because of the lazyness of take, but that's not the case. Why?

Comment: Try `take 5 [ (a,b,c) | a <- [1..], b <- [1..], c <- [1..]]` and you should see why

Comment: It **never** makes sense to have multiple generators (i.e. `<-`) with infinite length... only the last one will ever produce more than one value.

Comment: See [omega](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/control-monad-omega-0.3.1). It would make this work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the list for b to be related to c, and the list for a to be related to b.

The reason for this is a is started at 1, b is starting at 1, and then c is just counting up indefinitely. There are no triangles that have sides 1, 1, x>1.

A solution that should work would be 
`take 100 [(a,b,c) | c<-[1..], b<-[1..c], a<-[1..b], a^2 + b^2 == c^2]`

This solution works because now a will count up from 1 to b, simultaneously, b will count up from 1 to c, and the c just counts up like normal.

Comment: Depending on your expected answer, you might want `a<-[1..c]` instead. This would allow both (3,4,5) and (4,3,5) to appear in the full list of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

It wont't work because you asking to generate triple in the following manner

> [(1,1,1),(1,1,4),(1,1,9),(1,1,16),(1,1,25),(1,1,36),(1,1,49),(1,1,64),(1,1,81),(1,1,100),(1,1,121),(1,1,144),(1,1,169),(1,1,196),(1,1,225),(1,1,256),(1,1,289),(1,1,324),(1,1,361),(1,1,400),(1,1,441),(1,1,484),(1,1,529),(1,1,576),(1,1,625),(1,1,676),(1,1,729),(1,1,784),(1,1,841),(1,1,900),(1,1,961),(1,1,1024),(1,1,1089),(1,1,1156),(1,1,1225),(1,1,1296),(1,1,1369),(1,1,1444),(1,1,1521),(1,1,1600),(1,1,1681),(1,1,1764),(1,1,1849),(1,1,1936),(1,1,2025),(1,1,2116),(1,1,2209),(1,1,2304),(1,1,2401),(1,1,2500),(1,1,2601),(1,1,2704),(1,1,2809),(1,1,2916),(1,1,3025),(1,1,3136),(1,1,3249),(1,1,3364),(1,1,3481),(1,1,3600),(1,1,3721),(1,1,3844),(1,1,3969),(1,1,4096),(1,1,4225),(1,1,4356),(1,1,4489),(1,1,4624),(1,1,4761),(1,1,4900),(1,1,5041),(1,1,5184),(1,1,5329),(1,1,5476),(1,1,5625),(1,1,5776),(1,1,5929),(1,1,6084),(1,1,6241),(1,1,6400),(1,1,6561),(1,1,6724),(1,1,6889),(1,1,7056),(1,1,7225),(1,1,7396),(1,1,7569),(1,1,7744),(1,1,7921),(1,1,8100),(1,1,8281),(1,1,8464),(1,1,8649),(1,1,8836),(1,1,9025),(1,1,9216),(1,1,9409),(1,1,9604),(1,1,9801),(1,1,10000),(1,1,10201),(1,1,10404),(1,1,10609),(1,1,10816),(1,1,11025),(1,1,11236),(1,1,11449),(1,1,11664),(1,1,11881),(1,1,12100),(1,1,12321),(1,1,12544),(1,1,12769),(1,1,12996),(1,1,13225),(1,1,13456),(1,1,13689),(1,1,13924),(1,1,14161),(1,1,14400),(1,1,14641),(1,1,14884),(1,1,15129),(1,1,15376),(1,1,15625),(1,1,15876),(1,1,16129),(1,1,16384),(1,1,16641),(1,1,16900),(1,1,17161),(1,1,17424),(1,1,17689),(1,1,17956),(1,1,18225),(1,1,18496),(1,1,18769),(1,1,19044),(1,1,19321),(1,1,19600),(1,1,19881),(1,1,20164),(1,1,20449),(1,1,20736),(1,1,21025),(1,1,21316),(1,1,21609),(1,1,21904),(1,1,22201),(1,1,22500),(1,1,22801),(1,1,23104),(1,1,23409),(1,1,23716),(1,1,24025),(1,1,24336),(1,1,24649),(1,1,24964),(1,1,25281),(1,1,25600),(1,1,25921),(1,1,26244),(1,1,26569),(1,1,26896),(1,1,27225)

There is not bound for C, so haskell clearly never finds 100 triple such that 1^2 +1^2 = c^2.